# cheerio selection of a list

Tags: node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

On a page I need to scrape (with node.js and cheerio), I have this pattern:

```
<h2>
  <span id="2015"></span>
  <span class="ignore-me"></span>
</h2>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a title="TITLE1" href="HREF1"></a>
      <a class="image" title="ignore-me-1" href="ignore-me-1"></a>
    </li>
    ...
    <li>
      <a title="TITLE2" href="HREF2"></a>
      <a class="image" title="ignore-me-2" href="ignore-me-2"></a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I would like to extract a list with TITLEs an HREFs.

I am trying something like this:

```
$('h2 > span[id="2015"]').next('ol > li > a').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log('title:', element.attr('title'), 'href:', element.attr('href'));
});
```

without success (`each` loop is never entered...).

Any suggestion?

Comment: try this `$('h2 > span[id="2015"]').parent().next('div').find('ol > li > a')`

Comment: This is the correct answer! If you mind refactoring your comment as an answer (including the element title/href extraction), I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ol` element isn't actually the next element of `span#2015`. The `ol` element is inside a `div` which is the next element of `h2`. The right tree traversal is :

```
$('h2 > span[id="2015"]')
  .parent()
  .next('div')
  .find('ol > li > a:not([class])')
  .each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    console.log('title:', $el.attr('title'), 'href:', $el.attr('href'));
  });
```

Comment: You just forgot I asked for a **list**, so will add an `each()` after the `find()`. Furthermore, instead of: if (e.attr('title') I'll do: if (!e.attr('class'), since I have to ignore a elements without a class. For the rest, it's the solution (I forgot the `parent()`... :-(). Thanks!

Comment: okay, updated ans. note that you can use `a:not([class])` to filter elements without any class.

Answer (score 1):

The `h2` tag does not have an ID, thus your selector finds no results, nothing to loop over.

You could easily do it by looping anchor tags.

```
$("a").each(function(i, e) {
    if (e.attr('title') && e.attr('href')) console.log("... stuff ...");
});
```

Or you can give your `h2` an id, or remove the id from your selector. Many ways to loop.

Comment: Probably my question was not clear, sorry... The page I scrape is a public page, I can't control it... I need to get the `ol` list elements in a `div` after an `h2`element containing a `span` with a specific `id` ("2015").

Comment: However, your first remark is correct: I changed my code with `h2 > span[id="2015"]`, but no success, however.. :-(